# why does this for loop only loop once?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

what i'm trying to do is a simple practice code with a output like this:

```
user1 logged in at hh:mm
user2 logged in at hh:mm
...
```

so i wrote a basic for loop, but what i don't understand why it only runs once.

```
for user in $(who)
do
    USERID=$(echo $user | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1)
    LOGTIME=$(echo $user | tr -s ' '| cut -d' ' -f4)
    echo "$USERID logged in at $LOGTIME"
done
```

this echos the following:

```
user1
user2
user3 logged in at hh:mm
hh:mm
hh:mm
```

i've put echo lines in between to figure out what is going on and how to fix it, but the only thing i figured out is that the for loop is only running once so USERID and LOGTIME is just a long string with linebreaks. what am i doing wrong? (i did the IFS=$’\n’)

Comment: Try reading using while loop instead of for. `while read user  do echo $user done < $(who)`

Comment: [How to read stream field by field in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: @DigvijayS this didn't work for me. for some reason it gave me a 'no such file or directory' error on $(who)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
while read -r user tty mon day logtime; do
    echo "$user logged in at $logtime"
done < <(who)
```

Comment: thanks! but i had to change it a little. the result was "the default who(user id + etc) logged in at" without the logtime. so i put the USERID and LOGTIME code from the question between the do-done statement, changed echo statement, and it worked! again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/sh

who > stack

while [ $(wc -l stack) -gt 0 ]
do
  line=$(sed '1p' stack)
  USERID=$(echo ${line} | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1)
  LOGTIME=$(echo ${line} | tr -s ' '| cut -d' ' -f4)
  echo "${USERID} logged in at ${LOGTIME}"
  sed -i '1d' stack
done

rm -v ./stack
exit 0
```

If this does not work, provide me with an example of who output on your machine.

Comment: This is extremely inefficient. [@DigvijayS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62060234/why-does-this-for-loop-only-loop-once#comment109764035_62060234) has the right idea.

Comment: It's also transparent about what it is doing.  If the OP decides he does not want to use it, then that is up to him; but your statement is rejected.

Comment: i get what this is trying to do, but i have to agree with @l0b0 that it is a bit inefficient for what i'm trying to achieve. neverthless, thanks for the advice!